# Return generic CaseIterable-conforming type from function

Tags: swift, generics, enums, swift-protocols

I'm trying to implement a protocol that requires a function which should return the `Type` of a type that is conforming to `CaseIterable`. When I call that function, I expect to be able to call `.allCases` on the returned generic type. Unfortunately, the compiler won't let me.

```
protocol FooDataSource: class {
    func caseIterable<T: CaseIterable>(for foo: Foo) -> T.Type
}

class Foo {
    weak var dataSource: FooDataSource?

    func callAllCasesProperty() {
        let a = self.dataSource?.caseIterable(for: self).allCases
    }
}
```

When trying to run that code in a playground, I get:

> error: experiments.playground:7:58: error: generic parameter `T` could not be inferred `let a = self.dataSource?.caseIterable(for: self).allCases`

Is there a way I can achieve the intended functionality?

Comment: How does Swift supposed to infer the type `T`? You provide absolutely no information about it.

Comment: Let's say I only want to call .allCases.count, does it need to know the type on compile time?

Comment: `.allCases.count` of **what**? If you want to know how many case *something* has, you must specify that *something*. For example, you can't measure length or weight of some real life object X, unless you have it, can you? You can't abstract this away.

Comment: I see your point. Would you mind adding an answer if you think the question is valid?

Comment: Do you need the protocol? The generic function seems unrelated to the protocol.

Answer (score 3):

While I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to accomplish, it looks like you could use a generic function with some specific constraints on the type. By restricting T to RawRepresentable & CaseIterable, you can pass as an argument an enum type and call allCases in the function.

```
enum Direction: String, CaseIterable {
    case north
    case south
    case east
    case west
}

enum Weight: Int, CaseIterable {
    case Light = 1
    case Mid = 4
    case Heavy = 10
}

func genericMethod<T : RawRepresentable & CaseIterable>(enumType: T.Type) {
    for aCase in enumType.allCases {
        print(aCase.rawValue)
    }
}

genericMethod(enum: Direction.self) // prints -> north, south, east, west
genericMethod(enum: Weight.self) // prints -> 1, 4, 10
```

You can also further constraint the type T like this:

```
func genericMethodWithRawConstraint<T : RawRepresentable & CaseIterable>(enumType: T.Type) where T.RawValue == String {
    for aCase in enumType.allCases {
        print(aCase.rawValue)
    }
}

//Will not compile because Weight is of type Int
//genericMethodWithRawConstraint(enum: Weight.self)
```